# How to install JTS library in Solr 5.4.1?

Tags: solr, jts

I am trying to index polygons/circles in Solr 5.4.1 . But it is showing error like this. I am using solr document update to insert document.

```
Status: error
Error: Bad Request
Error:

{
  "responseHeader": {
   "status": 400,
   "QTime": 2
  },
  "error": {
  "msg": "Unknown Shape definition [Circle(4.56,1.23 d=0.0710)]",
  "code": 400
  }
}
```

I think that it is because of JTS library not being installed. There are various questions on how to install JTS in Solr 4.10.2 but Solr 5.4.1 is different. I am running it by Solr binary as in $SOLR_HOME/bin. Can anyone help me on this ?

Answer (score 0):

Place the JTS library jar file in the solr/server/lib/ext/.
Now, restart Solr.
It will automatically pick up JTS library.

Comment: I tried what you said but doesn't work for me. Is anything to do for work?

Comment: Could you please provide a link to download the jts jar file for solr 
    6.6.6?